# How to check if an array is increasing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I follow a javascript course and I am stuck with something. We get a website full of excercises and have to make all the test cases turn green.

We have to check if an array is increasing and return true if that is the case.If the next value is the same as the previous the function must also return true. All my test cases return false for some reason? And if I remove the else only one of the test cases is wrong (this one: [0,1,2,3,4,5,0]). [Here are the test cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNJqm.png)

```
function isIncreasing(xs) {
    var result = false;
    if (xs.length == 1 || xs.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= xs.length - 1; i++) {
        if (xs[i] == xs[i + 1] - 1 || xs[i] == xs[i + 1]) {
            result = true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walk through your code with the debugger, stopping at interesting lines and examining the values. You should be able to find the problem soon enough.

If you want to use a `for` loop, you can simplify your code, and omit the special casing for 0 and 1, while fixing the top of the loop condition:

```
function isIncreasing(xs) {
  var prev, cur;

  for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    cur = xs[i];
    if (i && cur !== prev && cur !== prev + 1) return false;
    prev = cur;
  }

  return true;
}
```

If you're allowed to use ES5 array methods, this can use `every`:

```
[1, 2, 3].every(function(elt, idx, arr) { 
  var prev = arr[idx - 1];
  return !idx || elt === prev || elt === prev + 1;
})
```

If you want to make your code more semantic and readable, define a well-named function:

```
function sameOrGreater(elt, idx, arr) { 
  var prev = arr[idx - 1];
  return !idx || elt === prev || elt === prev + 1;
}

[1, 2, 3].every(sameOrGreater)
```

To continue with this factoring, we can separate out two aspects of the solution. The first is to see if one value is the same as or one greater than another. The second is to take pairs of adjacent elements in an array. In other words, we would like to be able to write the solution as

```
pairs(xs).every(sameOrGreater)
```

`sameOrGreater` is easy:

```
function sameOrGreater(x, y) { return x === y || x === y - 1; }
```

`pairs` can be written as follows:

```
function pairs(array) {
  return array.slice(1).map(function(elt, idx, arr) {
    return [array[idx], elt];
  });
}

> pairs([1, 2, 3])
< [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

You might prefer to write `pairs` using a generator:

```
function* pairs(array) {
  let prev;
  for (const x of array) {
    yield [prev, x];
    prev = x;
  }
}
```

Alternatively we could write a version of `map` which takes a function to which are fed pairs, as follows:

```
function mapPairs(xs, fn) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < xs.length); i++) {
    result.push(fn(x[i - 1], x[i]));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now we can write the entire problem as

```
mapPairs(xs, sameOrGreater).every(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop tries to access an element outside of the array bounds on the last iteration (`i == xs.length - 1` and then `xs[i+1]`). A cleaner way would be to start with the second elem instead and compare with the previous, not the next one.

```js
function isIncreasing(xs) {
  
    for (var i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
        if (xs[i] !== xs[i - 1] && xs[i] != xs[i - 1] + 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
  
    return true;
}

console.log(isIncreasing([]));
console.log(isIncreasing([1]));
console.log(isIncreasing([1,2,3,4,4,5]));
console.log(isIncreasing([0,1,2,3,4,5,0]))
```

Also note how your function can be simplified (length checks and the result variable are actually not needed).

Comment: No, the original code actually included the last element and one extra past the last; it is given as `i <= xs.length - 1` but should be `i < xs.length - 1`. Also the spec seems unclear - `[1, 2, 3, 5]`, for instance, is untested, but given the original expression it would probably be disallowed.

Comment: Oh yes ofcourse! Dumb little mistake, the code works now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since no answer is using `Array.prototype.reduce`, which I think is perfect for this, here's a solution using `reduce`:

```js
var arrayIsAscending = [-1, 13, 14].reduce((outcome, value, index, array) => {
  if (!outcome) return false // if at least one item failed, this will always return false
  if (index === 0) return true // first item cannot be checked against a previous item
  return value > array[index-1]
}, true)

console.log(arrayIsAscending)
```

Of course, the function passed to reduce can be extracted and given a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
  isIncreasing = (array) => {
    for(i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
      if(array[i] < array[i + 1]) {}
      else if (i <= array.length && array[i] < array[i + 1]) return true;
      else return false;
    }
  }
```

this code uses a for loop to iterate the indexes of an array and the index higher than it to check if it's greater. Because `return` stops the function execution. I put an `if` statements that checks if it's incrementing, if it is true do nothing, but if it's not true stop the function execution as it is not incrementing. The `else if` just checks to see if it reaches the last index without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can adjust it like this:

```js
var isIncreasing = (arr) => {
  return (
    arr.every((v, i) => i === 0 || v >= arr[i - 1])
  );
};

console.log(isIncreasing([]));
console.log(isIncreasing([0]));
console.log(isIncreasing([1, 0]));
console.log(isIncreasing([1, 1, 1]));
console.log(isIncreasing([1, 1, 2, 3, 3]));
console.log(isIncreasing([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]))
```